# IOS: UINavigationItem button width

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am creating Cancel button with my own Background image this way:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onCancel)];

[leftBarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneButtonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[leftBarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneButtonInactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton];
[leftBarButton release];
```

**The problem I have, the button is too wide.** It is almost twice bigger than it should be. I have tried to change width property with no effect. I am running iOS5 and it is the same on retina and non-retina display (I have two versions of images: for retina and non-retina displays).

Is it possible to change the width in other way? I know, I can create button with custom view, but it is not so "native" and I will have to make "Graphic guy" to change the images.

**UPDATE**
Problem solved. It is not possible to edit System style buttons. It is necessary to create UIButton with custom background and create UIBarButtonItem with custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It is not possible to edit System style buttons. It is necessary to create **UIButton** with custom background and create **UIBarButtonItem** with custom view.